# Pass capitalised variables to django settings.configure()

Tags: django, environment-variables, django-settings

I am looking for a way to read from a list of variables and set them in Django settings using the [settings.configure()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/#django.conf.settings.configure) method:

```py
from django.conf import settings


def func(i):
    # do something and return

for item in items:
    settings.configure(item=func(item))
```

But have no idea how I could write this properly to get past the

```bash
TypeError: Setting 'item' must be uppercase.
```

Comment: Which settings are you trying to configure? As the error tells you, you can't use `item` as a setting name. At minimum, you'd need to call it `ITEM`. Per the docs page you linked _"Setting names **must** be all uppercase"_

Comment: `**{item: func(item)}`

Comment: Note it’s an error to call `configure()` more than once, or to call `configure()` after any setting has been accessed. So you have to use exactly one of either `configure()` or `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. Not both, and not neither. Refer to Django settings documentation for more on this. If you want to use the approach you wrote, add all items to a temp dict first and then pass it to `configure()` outside the loop.